# Multiple Transitions into one in JIRA Workflow

Tags: internet-explorer, workflow, jira

I am currently working on creating a workflow in JIRA that will help my team to better perform testing. Since, we are working on Web Development primarily, when it comes to testing I would like to have testing be done in IE 9, IE 10 and IE 11 before we can mark it as passed. I tried to do that through multiple transitions going into one status and one transition going out, and also tried adding a screen to allow the developer/tester checking which version of IE has been tested.

This is the workflow I currently have

Development started->Submitted to Code Review->Passed Code Review->

- If code does not include a UI Change it should display Pass Dev Testing and Failed Dev Testing
- If code included UI Change **Passed Dev Testing** should not be visible until all three browser testing have been checked

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @dat3450 The question is, how can I have Passed Dev Testing transition available only after all 3 transitions of browser testing have been completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you create three sub-tasks for testing each of the browser versions. Then you can have a condition that will only permit moving to the passed if all three subtasks are closed.

Comment: Is there a way to create a subtask through transition without any extra plugins?

Comment: No, out-of-the-box Jira does not provide the ability to create sub-tasks

Answer (score 0):

> The question is, how can I have Passed Dev Testing transition available only after all 3 transitions of browser testing have been completed

You can do it in only one transition: Just add three chkeckbox or "yes/no" select custom fields for the test and add a condition to the Workflow step that checks that all these three custom fields have a "true" or "yes" value. Such conditions for workflows are available in some free plugins like [Suite Utilities for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.googlecode.jira-suite-utilities/server/overview)

[image]